# To know when login timeout

Tags: c#, soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I nee to connect to web service to perform transaction. For this purpose I'm using class `NetSuiteService:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol`. In order to get service I need to login. I would like not to create web service and do login each time when I need to perform transaction. I have function that does it.

```
private static NetSuiteService Service { get; set; } = new NetSuiteService();


        private static void isOnline()
        {

                if (Service.applicationInfo != null) return;

                Service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                Service.applicationInfo = new ApplicationInfo();

                var passport = new Passport();
                passport.account = "aaa";
                passport.email = "bbb";
                var role = new RecordRef();
                passport.password = "999";
                try
                {

                    var status = Service.login(passport).status;
                    if (!status.isSuccess)
                    {
                        Log.ErrorFormat("can't login to NetSuite - {0}", status.statusDetail);
                        Service.applicationInfo = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("NetSuite login err", ex);
                }

        }
```

But sometimes my connection is time outed and I need to reconnect. In this situation I have exception while performing transaction.

Is it possible somehow to know was my session got timeout before making transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates the login passport, which you can add to your service

```
_service = new NetSuiteService();

Passport passport = new Passport();
passport.account = _custSettings["login.acct"];
passport.email = _custSettings["login.email"];
passport.password = _custSettings["login.password"];
RecordRef role = new RecordRef();
role.internalId = _custSettings["login.roleId"];
passport.role = role;

_service.passport = passport;
```

You only need to set this once and can now make all your Web API calls, without timeouts. So rather than using the Service.login() method, the passport will be automatically used with each API call made.

I am reading the login details from a config file, but you can insert this however works in your application.